# Are ALL "Loss Functions" in Statistical and Machine Learning Models Fundamentally "Noisy"?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, model, loss-functions, gradient-descent

**I am trying to better understand the meaning of "noise" with regards to function optimization.**

Up until now, I always thought of "noise" from a signal processing standpoint: for example - how to remove and filter out the noise component from some signal:

[image]

I also generally think of this in the context of Time Series Analysis, where a time series is separated into non-random components (e.g. seasonal) and random components (e.g. noise):

[image]

In both of these above cases, "Noise" is viewed as something with inherent "negative connotations", as something undesirable which is either hindering or further complicating the end goal of (usually) a forecasting or engineering project.

However, I am interested in "noise" from more of a Machine Learning and Optimization perspective. For instance, (I am not sure if this is correct) I have heard that since the "loss functions" of Machine Learning algorithms are always dependent on measurements from the real world - thus, any "loss function" of a Machine Learning algorithm is *always* considered to be a "noisy function":

[image]

**My Question:**

- **Is my understanding of this correct - are functions that are based on observed measurements fundamentally considered to be "Noisy"? Is this what the optimization of "Noisy" Functions is referring to?**
- I can understand that "Noisy" Functions contain "random noise" (as the name implies) which alters their "fidelity" with regards to the concept they are attempting to represent (i.e. an additional source of "difficulty" when attempting to use them for some applied purpose) - but are "Noisy" Functions inherent more "computationally expensive" to evaluate (e.g. their derivatives) compared to "Non-Noisy" and "Lesser-Noisy" Functions of similar complexity? **How exactly does the "Noisiness" of a function contribute to its computational complexity (to the extent that gradient-free methods are often used on "Noisy" Functions in order to reduce their "computational costs")?**
- I have heard the following argument being made on an informal level : Given that "Noisy" Functions are often more "computationally expensive" to optimize, and that no major theoretical results have been established on the convergence properties of gradient-based optimization algorithms on "Noisy" Functions - using gradient-free optimization algorithms (e.g. evolutionary algorithms, genetic algorithm, metaheuristics) might have certain advantages in optimizing such "Noisy" Functions.  **Have any significant theoretical results been established regarding the convergence properties of common optimization algorithms (e.g. gradient descent, stochastic gradient descent) on "Noisy" Functions?**

Thanks!

**References:**

- [http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ferris/talks/Informs-washington.pdf](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eferris/talks/Informs-washington.pdf)
- https://noisyopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
- https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01306636v2/document

Comment: You're on this site for a while, so as a reminder: please do not ask multiple questions at once, but split them to separate questions.

Comment: Given that noisy meaning having stochastic terms in functions. There is a distinction between noisy functions and noisy optimisation. Common machine learning loss functions are all deterministic, i.e., do not have stochastic terms. Learning is noisy though, i.e., SGD.

Answer (score 5):

- Noise does not have negative connotations in statistics or machine learning. In both cases, we are dealing with random variables, so if $\mathbf{x}$ is a random variable, then any function of it $f(\mathbf{x})$ will be a random variable as well. In such a case, the output of the function would be random, non-deterministic, or “noisy”.
- It is not the loss functions that are noisy. Loss functions are evaluated on random variables, and any functions of random variables are noisy.
- Optimizing a noisy function is hard because it is non-deterministic. You have no guarantee that the function evaluated on one sample would have the same minimum or maximum as when evaluated on another sample. So when optimizing it, you need somehow account for the fact that you're dealing with a random variable. This is where the the complexity comes from.
- As for literature, any literature on statistics, machine learning, or optimizing noisy functions would be dealing with this subject. It's too broad to give a specific answer.

Comment: @ Tim: Thank you so much for your answer! I will have to remember this: "noisy optimization" refers to optimizing a mathematical function that is based of a random variable, instead of a deterministic function.

Comment: I just wanted to add: Do you know why optimizing noisy functions are considered to be more "computationally expensive" compared to optimizing non-noisy functions? For instance, I have heard that evaluating the derivative of a noisy function is more computationally expensive compared to the derivative of a non-noisy function is this true? With this being said, I am still trying to understand why using Gradient Free Optimization Techniques (e.g. evolutionary algorithms, genetic algorithms, metaheuristics) can be advantageous when optimizing noisy functions.  Why is this so? Thank you so much!

Comment: @stats555 imagine you have two points, say x=1 and y= 2, which one is larger? That's obvious, right? Now imagine you are given two coins and need to decide which one has a higher probability of landing heads, can you judge this only by looking at the coins as in the first example?

Comment: A caveat: In statistics you typically compute estimators from criterion functions. These are typically simple averages of loss functions that depend on data and an unknown set of parameters, e.g. $f(x,\theta)$. In that sense the criterion is a noisy measure of the expected loss function $\mathbb{E}[f(x,\theta)]$ over X (which is deterministic). The sample criterion typically converges to the expectation because of a uniform weak law of large numbers. In that sense “ideal” large sample criterion is deterministic, and finite samples always generate noisy versions of that criterion.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies!

Comment: @ Tim: I was thinking about your example with the coins - I agree. Based on a single flip of both coins, it is impossible to know which coin has a higher probability of landing on heads. I am having a bit of trouble extending this example to understand why it can be more difficult to optimize noisy functions. Is it because the parameters within the noisy function depend on your data, and the data could have been different - therefore you are dealing with a more volatile function?

Comment: @ Tim: Just to clarify, Noisy Functions are NOT more computationally expensive to optimize compared to non-noisy functions, and therefore evolutionary algorithms  in general would not present any significant advantages in optimizing noisy functions compared to gradient based methods? Thank you so much!

Comment: @  ecnmetrician: is this the crux of the matter? noisy functions are more difficult to optimize because of theoretical convergence properties of non-deterministic functions - and NOT because they are more computationally expensive? Using this logic, it would appear that using evolutionary algorithms to optimize noisy functions would NOT present any significant advantages compared to gradient based methods? Thank you so much!